# SAS Java libraries

Tags: java, groovy, sas

I have to work with data grids (RTDM Tables) in Java/Groovy. This piece of code will be run by a SAS process. To be more precise, I'm importing the following libraries:

```
import com.sas.analytics.ph.common.RTDMTable
import com.sas.analytics.ph.common.RTDMTable.Row
import com.sas.analytics.ph.common.RTDMTable.Column
```

However I couldn't find the documentation for these RTDMTable, Row and Column objects. I've been Googling for 5 hours now, both SAS and Java documentations, but without any luck.

Can someone point me to a reference where all the possible functions and values of these objects are listed?

Comment: Sorry- requests for finding offsite documentation are not on topic here, for various reasons (you can look at [ask] and the [help] for more information).